# How can I change the value of a submit button

Tags: html, forms

I'm creating a register form which requires a 'check if username available' button.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <div id="availablity">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php _e("Username") ?>" style="float: left;"/>
        <span id="availability_status" style="float: left;">icon here</span>
        <input type="submit" name="check" value="<?php _e("Check") ?>" style="float: left;"/>
        <div style="clear: both;"
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="mail" value="<?php _e("E-Mail") ?>" id="" class="input" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e("Register") ?>" id="register" />
    <p class="statement"><?php _e("A password will be e-mailed to you.") ?></p>
</form>
```

The button, on line 5, contains text that is translatable, hence the value will change. The code works, when 'Check' is clicked an extra query named 'check' is submitted, and clicking 'Submit' the 'check' is disregarded. Is there any way I can change the text while keeping a default value (possibly '1'). Currently, all I can do server side is check if a query named 'check' was submitted and not bother with it's value.

Comment: Yes, you can set a hidden field with some value and then check that instead of check button and proceed!

Comment: @MrLister I understand the `<button>` but it's HTML5, causing my code to not work on older browsers. How can a hidden control solve this? I want 'check' to be sent only if the button is clicked but have a consistent value. Currently the value is a translated string "Check".

Comment: @MrLister Sorry my mistake. I see that it's functionality was extended with HTML5 and not introduced. In that case `<button>` is exactly what I want.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer. And the other issue, you said in your question that when "clicking 'Submit' the 'check' is disregarded", which caused people to assume you wanted to remember the fact that "Check" had been clicked, when the other button was clicked.

Comment: If you don't want your button to submit the form, be sure to do `type="button"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an `<input>`, where the value is exactly the same as the text on the screen, use a `<button>` where the text on the screen can be anything you want.
In other words, change

```html
<input type="submit" name="check" value="<?php _e("Check") ?>"
  style="float: left;"/>
```

to

```
<button type="submit" name="check" value="1" style="float: left;">
 <?php _e("Check") ?>
</button>
```

so that it will always have the value 1, no matter the text! (Of course you can use whatever value you want.)